# cp throws 'cannot access' even when sudo'ing

Tags: permissions, sudo

I have a directory `~/c9/support/npm` that is owned by my account. I have a target directory `/mnt/ws/users/jan/npm` that doesn't exist yet, but `/users/jan` is owned by `usr_jan`. Now I want to copy the folder to it's new location and I do:

```
sudo -Hu usr_jan cp -r ~/c9/support/npm /mnt/ws/users/jan/npm
```

Now it throws:

```
cp: cannot access /home/cloud9/c9/support/npm
```

Is it like prohibited to access data from someone else's home folder, even with sudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, "sudo -Hu usr_jan" will do everything as that user, with their home directory, and not root.  Use "sudo cp -pr /home/cloud9/c9/support/npm /mnt/ws/users/jan/" if you want to keep permissions from the source directory.  cp -p keeps ownership/permissions if run by root.